# DotnetDebugger.setDebuggerProperty' wasn't found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, blazor-webassembly

Visual Studio 2022 preview is getting me this warning all the time while debugging and the Hot Reload stopped working.

```
DotnetDebugger.setDebuggerProperty' wasn't found
```

The complete message :

```
fail: Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy[0] sending error response for id: msg-472A7FD7AA508BF6FFA0C62408542776:::1072 -> [Result: IsOk: False, IsErr: True, Value: , Error: {   "code": -32601,   "message": "'DotnetDebugger.setDebuggerProperty' wasn't found" } ]
```

All my projects are Blazor WebAssembly

Any idea?

Comment: Im having the same error message popping up in the console (Vs2022 Preview + Chrome Browser + Blazor WebAssembly).
Hotload wasn't working for me either, but then I found a hotload option in my Visual Studio Settings that wasn't enabled and at least Hotload started working.

Comment: In my VS are enabled, I tried everything and no way to solve it...

Comment: Same issue here. VS2022 Preview + Chrome + Blazor WebAssembly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening, but it happened to me and decided to repair the installation of visual studio. With that, everything started to work like before.

As I said before, I don´t know why it happens, but that worked for me

Comment: Btw, I hope I'm not that late, because this post is from 1 month ago

Comment: It's not late, I did repair the installation, but it didn't work for me, I'll try a fresh install

Comment: @JoseManuelLepe did you manage to solve that problem? I'm facing the same issue and I cannot find any solution for it.

Comment: The problem disappears after upgrade the project from net 6 to net 7

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappears after upgrade the blazor webassembly project from net 6 to net 7

Comment: In my case this problem occurred when I updated project form net 6 to net 7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with DotNet 6 and i resolve it by setting DebugType to portable  in the client project file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;$(DefineConstants)DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Didn't work here

Answer (score 0):

If I use the browser with Chromium, this error will occur. When I use firefox, the error disappears